# Failed to convert UTF-8 character to upper case in C++

Tags: c++, localization

I am calling `std::setlocale(LC_ALL, ".UTF-8")` and right after this I would like to convert  `æ` (U+00E6) letter to its upper-case representation `Æ` (U+00C6). It does not convert the character at all. However, the `std::towupper(character)` function fails in this case while operating well for other characters like U+0105 to U+0104 and U+0183 to U+0182. Could anyone indicate what may be a cause of the failure? Please note that I am passing `uint32_t` to the `std::towupper()` function.

Comment: Curiously in [iso document](https://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC35/WG5/docs/30112d10.pdf) the æ is the lower of Æ, but Æ is not the upper conversion of æ! Æ is only in the totitle conversion of æ.